# Ng-repeat is not showing any data in select options in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, dropdown, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

Ng-repeat is not showing any data in select options. is there any different way to show option value in select for ng-repeat

When I am using without class="selectpicker" in select tag. Its working fine. How can I use bootstrap select with ng-repeat.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.11/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.11/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


 <div>
<select ng-model="selEmployee" name="selEmployee" class="selectpicker">
   <option value=0>All</option>
   <option ng-repeat="employee in employees" value="{{employee.Ldap | lowercase}} ">{{employee.FirstName}} {{employee.LastName}}</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-options:

```
 <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Without `class="selectpicker` is working fine. But I want Live search on dropdown. So that I am using `class="selectpicker` which is not working together with `ng-options` or`ng-repeat`.